# How to open a word document in Firefox using JSP, Tomcat 8

Tags: jsp, tomcat, ms-word

I am trying to open an existing word document in Firefox but no success. Every time I click on the link that should open a new tab and render the word document I am prompted by following window

[image]

Not sure if this has anything to do with the tech stack but I am using JSP and Tomcat 8.

## fbr.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/msword; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Features By Release</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=file:///C:/nital/my-pet-projects/istore/resources/istore-tax-service-read-me.docx");
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a content-type header. Just before your line of JSP code add:

application/msword

so

```
<%
response.setContentType("application/msword");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=file:///C:/nital/my-pet-projects/istore/resources/istore-tax-service-read-me.docx");
%>
```

Comment: It still gives me the same prompt box and then when I select MS Word from the "Open with" combo box it opens a completely blank word document.

Answer (score 0):

First, browsers don't know how to open Word documents in browser (aside from IE). To do that in other browsers you'll need a Flash app that can do it. And then it only makes sense as a preview. If anyone is going to edit it, its better to cause it to open in Word.

Second, take the path out of the filename.  It doesn't make sense to put the local path there.

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=istore-tax-service-read-me.docx");
```

Third, this is not a Word document. This is a HTML file!

Fourth, This is an empty HTML file.  There is nothing in the body.  Setting the content-disposition to `file:///C:/nital/my-pet-projects/istore/resources/istore-tax-service-read-me.docx` in the body does *not* cause that file to be read by JSP. If you are trying to return that file, you're going to have to open it and read it, and print it byte by byte to the `response` (without writing out any HTML).

Fifth, if you were returning a real Word document from JSP, you'd put the `response.setHeader` *before* any output.